# Mocha + Chai testing Mongoose model schemas having issues with timestamps

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I am testing my express app that uses `Mongoose` ORM to handle mongodb, but I have come across a small issue in the testing.

I have tried the following:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const schema = new Schema({
  password: String,
  email: String,
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const admin = this;
  if (admin.isModified('password')) {
    admin.password = bcrypt.hashSync(admin.password, 8);
  }
  next();
});
schema.methods.verifyPassword = function (password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = model('Admin', schema);
```

Along with the mocha + chai test of the following configuration for starting up a mocha test

```
process.env.DATABASE_URL = 'localhost:27017'
process.env.DATABASE_NAME = 'funtime'
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'

const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const chaiThings = require('chai-things')
const timekeeper = require('timekeeper')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

chai.use(chaiThings)
chai.use(chaiHttp)
chai.should()

// Clearing DB function for beforeEach on tests
const clearDB = (callback) => {
  console.log('clearing dbs...')
  for (let i in mongoose.connection.collections) {
    mongoose.connection.collections[i].deleteMany(() => {})
  }
  return
}

const now = new Date()
now.setHours(10)
now.setMinutes(0)
now.setSeconds(0)
now.setMilliseconds(0)
timekeeper.freeze(now)

require('./factory')

console.log('Tests starting...')

before(() => {
  require('../lib/config/db')
})

after((done) => {
  timekeeper.reset()
  clearDB()
  console.log('Tests done!')
  done()
})
```

I am using Docker and docker compose to start my express server and mongodb instance, therefore the need for env variables.

in the line at `before(() => {})`, I required my `db` config which has the following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { mongoose: mongooseConfig } = require('./index');

const connectWithRetry = () => {
  console.log('Retrying Mongodb connection');
  mongoose.connect(mongooseConfig.uri, mongooseConfig.options)
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`Could not connect to MongoDB: ${err}:${err.stack}`);
      setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000);
    });
};
connectWithRetry();

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  mongoose.connection.close(() => {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected due to app termination');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

The error I receive is as thus when I run the command `./node_modules/.bin/mocha \"./tests/**/*.js\" --timeout 10000 --exit`:

```
Invalid schema configuration: `FakeDate` is not a valid type at path `updatedAt`.
```

Not sure what is wrong here

## EDIT (Solved)

By removing `timekeeper` the problem is solved. Thanks @jeffheifetz for his comment and help!

Comment: I'm only guessing, but `FakeDate` is most likely from TimeKeeper. Try running without the freeze and I bet the error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as an answer since you aren't supposed to answer in comments.

I'm only guessing, but FakeDate is most likely from TimeKeeper. Try running without the freeze and I bet the error will disappear